# Sticky Footer on mobile devices overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a footer as follows:

```
<div class="footer-content">
    <div class="footer-left">
        <p>The content of this site is owned by MR X, or their respective copyrights holders.</p>
        <p>No part of this site may be copied or reproduced without permission.  Per request, non commercial rights to use any content can be released.</p>
        <p>Thank you for viewing the site!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right">
        <a href="http://www.azularis.com" target="_blank">Designed and Created by Jango Puppies</a>
    </div>
</div>

html body Footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 1%, black 38%, black 66%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%, transparent), color-stop(38%, black), color-stop(66%, black));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 1%, black 38%, black 66%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 1%, black 38%, black 66%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 1%, black 38%, black 66%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1%, black 38%, black 66%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-8 */
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
html body Footer .footer-content {
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 102.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
html body Footer .footer-content .footer-left {
  width: calc(100% - 20rem);
  float: left;
}
html body Footer .footer-content .footer-left p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
html body Footer .footer-content .footer-right {
  float: right;
  width: 12rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
html body Footer .footer-content .footer-right a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

When I view this footer on the browser, it looks great.  It sticks to the bottom if there is not enough content and it shows up only after I scroll to the bottom if there is a lot of content (I intend it like this) and there are no issues.  When I view this footer on my android cellphone the footer sticks to the bottom but it overlaps the text.  Live demo at [claymation.azularis.com][1].

How can I prevent this on mobile devices?  Should I be using a different kind of sticky footer?

Comment: html body Footer?? this doesn't seem right. You are not giving the Proper HTML code for this CSS.

Comment: actually, the body can be used if it has a certain class style `<body class="style1>"`, such as `body.style1` or something like that. Since there is no indication of that, it can be removed as well the tag html and body. It clutters up your css file on data that is irrelevant to read.